# Protocol buffer. Use already defined c++ enums

Tags: c++, enums, protocol-buffers

I have an enum defined in a C++ header file. I want to use it inside a Protocol Buffer message. Is there any way to import this enum contained in .h file without duplicating it as a ProtocolBuffer-enum and avoiding any conversion?

Example:

- header.h:

```
enum Sample {A, B, C}
```

- protoMessage.proto:

```
syntax="proto2";

import "header.h"; //HOW CAN I DO THIS?

message SampleMessage{
   required Sample field =1;

}
```

Comment: Write a script that gets run as part of your build system, to automate generation of `.proto` files? Basic scripting.

Comment: If I understood correctly you will get two different enums, leading to compatibility mechanism to implement. I meant to use directly the same enum, so that it can be used in the c++ system and also in the generated .pb.cc class @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Define it once in the protocol buffers and use that from C++.